# Is it possible to implemet a Ruby-like internal DSL in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, dsl

Is it possible to implement an internal DSL in a language without macros?  Has anyone succeeded in implementing a Ruby-like internal DSL in python?

I am trying to develop a simple state machine with a more intuitive syntax like:

```
start -> Event -> Next ->Action
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please take the time to properly proof-read your question: it had some very obvious errors in it, and you didn't use a single capital.

Comment: am trying to develop a simple state machine with a more intuitive syntax like start ->  Event  -> Next  ->Action

Comment: @Bart attack the idea  not the formatting...  and in any case who cares about capitalization?

Comment: @mossplix, take it easy, I'm not attacking you. I simply asked you to take the time to properly ask a question. Using capitalization and checking for spelling errors before pressing the "submit" results in more readable posts. And I am positive that most people answering questions here appreciate you taking the time to capitalize the start of your sentences. But hey, if you make a big fuss out of it, I'll just revert my edits and -1 the question because of the (IMO) bad formatting.

Comment: stack overflow is Wiki style... when there is a typo in the question or 'obvious errors' hypothetically anyone can go in and  edit it

Comment: The question suggests Ruby has macros. It doesn't.

Comment: @mossplix, that is no reason to be lazy and not proof read your question and using a capital from time to time. Just writing a sloppy question in the hope that someone will come along and improve it, is IMO not the way to ask (or answer) here on SO. Sure, anyone can make a typo from time to time, but please take the time to write in coherent English.

Comment: Capitilization issues aside, +1 for an interesting and challenging question. Can you post example code of what you'd like to write?

Comment: @steenslag  proc can act as a poor man's macro

Comment: @mossplix Let's be silent, if the lispers read this , they would trample all over us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a beautiful State Machine framework, in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095930/is-there-a-beautiful-state-machine-framework-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a bit of trouble grokking your question.

AFAIU, you are asking

> Can you implement a Ruby-like internal DSL in a language without macros?

And the answer to that is obviously "Yes", since Ruby doesn't have macros.

Comment: Sorry my bad . my question was >> Is it possible to implement an internal dsl in python?